# program linking fails when using custom built gcc

Tags: c++, gcc, linker

I'm running a fedora 21 distribution, in which the default gcc is 4.9.
I have a custom built gcc/g++ 4.8 in /usr/local/gcc48 (for instance, cuda requires gcc =< 4.8, and i use update-alternatives to chose this one)
I have been compiling a few small programs with this version 4.8 without problem so far.

Now, I have been given a source code which makes uses of vtk libraries and others. If I use default gcc 4.9, cmake and make work fine.
However, when using gcc48, I get:

```
/usr/lib64/vtk/libvtkCommonDataModel.so.1: référence indéfinie vers « std::__throw_out_of_range_fmt(char const*, ...)@GLIBCXX_3.4.20 »
/lib64/libicuuc.so.52: référence indéfinie vers « __cxa_throw_bad_array_new_length@CXXABI_1.3.8 »
collect2: erreur: ld a retourné 1 code d'état d'exécution
CMakeFiles/main.dir/build.make:365: recipe for target '../bin/main'   failed
make[2]: *** [../bin/main] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:60: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/main.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/main.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:76: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I understand that is it a linker error, I tried to point LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/gcc48/lib or LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/gcc48/lib64, but i'm stuck.

What is the problem here ?

Thanks

Answer (score 14):

`__cxa_throw_bad_array_new_length` was added in **GCC 4.9**. That's what the **@CXXABI_1.3.8** version suffix means. You can look up those version codes here: 
https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/abi.html

This error means that you are trying to link an object file `/usr/lib64/vtk/libvtkCommonDataModel.so.1` compiled by GCC 4.9 or later with `libstdc++.so` or `libsupc++.so` from GCC 4.8 or earlier. Either rebuild `libvtkCommonDataModel.so` with GCC 4.8, or link against the correct libstdc++.so.

**Edit:**
Actually, if you want to compile with a newer version of GCC but run with an older libstdc++.so, that can be done.

1. Compile with `-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0` if you want to compile with GCC 5+ and run with libstdc++.so from older GCC. See https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1153109 and [Using dual ABI](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc%2B%2B/manual/using_dual_abi.html) in the libstdc++ manual.
2. Link against [stdc++compat.cpp](https://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/file/tip/build/unix/stdc%2B%2Bcompat/stdc%2B%2Bcompat.cpp) containing back-compat hacks from Mozilla. You can also take a look at my [modified version](https://bitbucket.org/rbv/ohrrpgce-svn/src/wip/lib/stdc++compat.cpp?at=wip&fileviewer=file-view-default) which doesn't depend on any Mozilla headers, but it's slightly out of date.
   In particular, this defines a stub `__cxa_throw_bad_array_new_length`.

Answer (score 4):

It would be helpful if you post the error message in English.

It appears that the undefined symbol is `__cxa_throw_bad_array_new_length`. The functions `__cxa`... come from the C++ runtime library. G++ usually ships with it's own version of this library, called `libsupc++`. I would guess that the custom-built G++ can not find this library or is emitting a reference to a symbol which is not in the newer (4.9) `libsupc++`. Try compiling the `libsupc++` source that ships with your custom version of G++ and directing the linker toward it. You may also need to do this for `libstdc++`.