# undefined reference gcc cxa

Tags: c++, gcc, linker

I'm trying to compile a program with make, but I get stuck on a error raised (see below) :

```
gcc -Wall -g -O2 -I. -I../include -I/usr/include/libxml2/ -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/ -I/usr/include/geotiff/ -I/usr/local/hdf4/hdf-4.2.11/hdf4/include/ -I/usr/local/hdf-eos/hdfeos/include/ -I -I -o convert_lpgs_to_espa convert_lpgs_to_espa.o -L../lib -l_espa_format_conversion -l_espa_raw_binary -l_espa_common -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ -lxml2 -L/usr/lib/ -lgeotiff -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ -ltiff -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ -ljpeg -L -ljbig -L/usr/local/hdf-eos/hdfeos/hdfeos2/lib -lgctp -L -lz -lm 
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicuuc.so.52: référence indéfinie vers « __cxa_throw_bad_array_new_length@CXXABI_1.3.8 »
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:95: recipe for target 'convert_lpgs_to_espa' failed
make[1]: *** [convert_lpgs_to_espa] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/project/$folders$/tools'
Makefile:6: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Following this close question : [program linking fails when using custom built gcc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29230777/program-linking-fails-when-using-custom-built-gcc), I purge and reinstall libstdc++-4.9-dev.

I'm running 
Ubuntu 15.04 with gcc (Ubuntu 4.9.2-10ubuntu13) 4.9.2

How can I resolve this issue ?

Answer (score 4):

It's because you link using `gcc` instead of `g++`. The difference is that the `g++` command adds the C++ runtime library when linking.

You can either change from using `gcc` to `g++`, or manually link with the C++ runtme library by adding `-lstdc++`.

Comment: Hi, I have a similar issue but with a slight difference: https://askubuntu.com/questions/940237/cmake-build-issue-undefined-reference-to-std-cxx11basic-stringchar-std

Do you have any idea?