# Unable to load dynamic library 'intl.so': undefined symbol: __cxa_throw_bad_array_new_length)

Tags: libstdc++, php-7.2

After installing an new version of *intl* (source: [here](https://light-code.ru/blog/post/update-icu-in-ubuntu/)), I added `extension=intl.so` to my **php.ini** file (**/etc/opt/remi/php72/php.ini**).

But when I restart my *Nginx* server, I get this warning:

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'intl.so'
>   (tried: /usr
>   /lib64/php/modules/intl.so (/usr/lib64/php/modules/intl.so: undefined
>   symbol: __
>   cxa_throw_bad_array_new_length)

I saw in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29230777/program-linking-fails-when-using-custom-built-gcc) post, that this is a linking problem, and that I should "link" **intl.so** against the correct **libstdc++.so**

(Indeed, I compiled *intl.so* with gcc7.1 and it says that the present *libstdc++.so* should be from gcc4.8)

Here is the result of **"locate libstdc++":**

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.2/libstdc++.so
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.2/32/libstdc++.so
/usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6
/usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.19
/usr/share/gdb/auto-load/usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.19-gdb.py
/usr/share/gdb/auto-load/usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.19-gdb.pyc
/usr/share/gdb/auto-load/usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.19-gdb.pyo
```

**Problem:** I don't know how to do this linking, and what it means exactly.

Thanks for your help.